# Extract page number to use within the \hyperlink command

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, page-numbering

Consider the following (non-compiling) example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Test~A}
\label{sec:A}
Test
\newpage

\section{Test~B}
\label{sec:B}
\hyperlink{page.\pageref{sec:A}}{Something}

\end{document}
```

How do I extract the page number of, say, the page with the `Test A` section, so that I can use it within the first argument of the `\hyperlink` command? (`\pageref` is not allowed but I don't know what else to try.)

Comment: why don't you use `\hyperlink[sec:A]{Something}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That gives the warning `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{[} has 
been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one` and then it links to the first page (also in larger documents where the section isn't on the first page).

Comment: Sorry I meant `\hyperref[sec:A]{Something}`

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks alot.

Comment: To answer your question, look at \getpagerefnumber (documented in refcount, but available from hyperref).

Answer (score 1):

Using Ulrike's comment: Using something like `\hyperref[sec:A]{Something}` worked according to the OP's response.